# Interpretation of zero energy Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, scattering

Consider two identical bosons with Hamiltonian given by:
$$H_{2} = -\nabla_{x_{1}}^{2}-\nabla_{x_{2}}^{2}+V(x-y)$$
acting on the subspace of symmetric functions on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$. Here, $V$ is a symmetric, positive function which we can assume to have compact support. Changing to the center of mass coordinates $R = \frac{1}{2}(x_{1}+x_{2})$ and $r = x_{1}-x_{2}$, this Hamiltonian becomes:
$$H_{2} = -\nabla_{R}^{2}-\nabla_{r}^{2}+V(r)$$
now acting on functions $\psi = \psi(R,r)$. Decomposing $\psi(R,r) = \phi(R)\varphi(r)$, the Schrödinger equation is separable:
$$-\nabla_{R}^{2}\phi(R) = E_{R}\phi(R) \quad \mbox{and} \quad -\nabla_{r}^{2}\varphi(r) +V(r)\varphi(r) = E_{r}\varphi(r)$$
and the total energy is $E = E_{R}+E_{r}$.

By the hypothesis on $V$, we can consider the zero energy equation:
$$-\nabla_{r}^{2}\varphi(r) + V(r)\varphi(r) = 0$$
How can the solution $\varphi(r)$ of the latter equation be interpreted? It should describe a single particle moving in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ under the influence of the potential $V$ but with zero energy? It seems strange to me, in particular because there is a kinetic energy term there.

Comment: I mean, it depends on what $V$ is.  If $V=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$, then there *is no* state of energy $E_r=0$.  On the other hand, if $V=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2-V_0$, and $V_0$ is large enough that it pulls the first bound state to zero energy, then... there you go. An energy being equal to zero *on its own* means (essentially) nothing. It is only energy *differences* that matter. (This is true in classical mechanics as well, so this isn't really a QM problem.) The potential energy is only unique up to an arbitrary additive constant.

Comment: I am going to edit the post to make the hypothesis on $V$ clearer.

Comment: If $V$ is a strictly non-negative function, than I'm pretty sure that there are no solutions for which $E_r=0$.

Comment: Yes, I accidentally changed the sign. It is corrected now, thanks!

Comment: There is a theorem governing the Schrödinger equation, that any normalisable state cannot have energy eigenvalue smaller than the least value of the potential, simply by analysing the shape of the wavefunction as required by Schrödinger equation. So march is correct, there cannot be $E_r=0$ if $V>0$

Answer (score 1):

> Here, $V$ is a symmetric, positive function...

OK, positive, not non-negative. So, $V$ is nowhere zero.

> ...the Schrödinger equation is separable...
> $$-\nabla_{r}^{2}\varphi(r) +V(r)\varphi(r) = E_{r}\varphi(r)$$

> By the hypothesis on $V$, we can consider the zero energy equation:
> $$-\nabla_{r}^{2}\varphi(r) + V(r)\varphi(r) = 0$$

I guess you can consider it, but there is no such function $\varphi$ that satisfies your above equation.

You can prove this by reducto ad absurdum.

Assume such a $\varphi$ exists, then:
$$
\langle\varphi|H|\varphi\rangle = 0
$$
$$
=\langle\varphi|T|\varphi\rangle + \langle \varphi| V|\varphi\rangle
$$
$$
\ge\langle \varphi|V|\varphi\rangle\;,
$$
(since $T$ is non-negative.)
$$
> 0\;,
$$
(since $V$ is positive.)

But the above inequality says:
$$
0>0\;,
$$
which is false. Thus we have proved that such a $\varphi$ can not exist.